# In Woocommerce, filter out certain related products by text or class

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In the related products section, I would like to filter out certain products. I cannot simply hide these products from the shop as I want to use them in the up-sells section.

In the related.php file, is there any argument I can use to filter out certain products? The products I want to filter, all contain the word "set" in them, and they also have a class "setBadge". Can I use these to somehow filter them out? (I cannot use css for this as if I use display: none they leave an empty space, I want to exclude them from the loop).

```
$args = apply_filters('woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
    'post_type'             => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'no_found_rows'         => 1,
    'posts_per_page'        => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby'               => $orderby,
    'post__in'              => $related,
    'post__not_in'          => array($product->id)
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a simple way to do this without $wpdb but you can try something like this maybe-

```
$search_query = 'iPhone air pods';
$break_query = explode(' ', $search_query);
$final_params = [];

/* $break_query = array(
    'iphone',
    'air',
    'pods'
); */

foreach( $break_query as $q ) {
    $args = array(
        'key' => '_price',
        'value' => $q,
        'compare' => '<=',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    );

    array_push( $final_params, $q );
}

$params = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
        'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            $final_params
        )
);
```

This code haven't been tested but what i did here is that-
I've splitted the main query per word and then I've dynamically created the $params array. The relation is "OR" so if any of these keywords are found, the product will be displayed.

Another option is to use WooCommerce's default search-

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/'  ) ); ?>">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _e( 'Search for:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
    <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search Products&hellip;', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
</form>
```